# How can I inspect stack frame in lldb or gdb?

Tags: gdb, lldb

I would like to view a complete function stack frame in either lldb or gdb, which includes:

- function arguments
- old ebp
- return address
- local variables

What should I do? Can anyone give me an example?

I‘ve tried using `finish` command, `frame info` ... but I am confused about the meaning of the outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GDB, you can view the stack using the `backtrace` command, or `bt` for short, this will give output like:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  func_c (str=0x402010 "this is a string", num=3) at test.cc:11
#1  0x000000000040113d in func_b (arg=..., num=129, str=0x402010 "this is a string") at test.cc:16
#2  0x000000000040116f in func_a (arg=..., str=0x402010 "this is a string") at test.cc:23
#3  0x0000000000401199 in main () at test.cc:30
```

The number on the left is the frame number, initially, frame #0, the most recent frame will be selected.  You can select another frame using the `up` and `down` commands, or by just using `frame NUM`, e.g. `frame 2`:

```
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x000000000040116f in func_a (arg=..., str=0x402010 "this is a string") at test.cc:23
23    func_b (arg, var + 6, str);
```

If you loose track of which frame you have selected, just use the `frame` command without any arguments and GDB will remind you.

With a frame selected we can view the arguments with `info args`:

```
(gdb) info args 
arg = {
  a = 1,
  b = 2
}
str = 0x402010 "this is a string"
```

Notice how with `info args` the argument called `arg` is now presented as its full value, while in `backtrace`, or `frame` command output GDB only printed `...`.  This is because `arg` is not a scalar, GDB is trying to reduce the size of the frame line.  You can adjust this behaviour with `set print frame-args all`, and restore the default behaviour with `set print frame-args scalar`.

On x86-64 you can view the stack frame address in the `info frame` output:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 2, frame at 0x7fffffffad80:
 rip = 0x40116f in func_a (test.cc:23); saved rip = 0x401199
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffada0, caller of frame at 0x7fffffffad50
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffad70, args: arg=..., str=0x402010 "this is a string"
 Locals at 0x7fffffffad70, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffad80
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffad70, rip at 0x7fffffffad78
```

The first line `Stack level 2, frame at 0x7fffffffad80:` contains the address you want.  But you can always confirm this, the frame address in one frame will be the stack-pointer address in the previous frame, so:

```
(gdb) up
#3  0x0000000000401199 in main () at test.cc:30
30    func_a (f, "this is a string");
(gdb) p $rsp
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffad80
```

Which seems to line up.  The `info frame` output also told us the return address with this line `rip = 0x40116f in func_a (test.cc:23); saved rip = 0x401199`, the `saved rip = 0x401199` is the address you want.  Again we can confirm this in the previous frame:

```
(gdb) frame
#3  0x0000000000401199 in main () at test.cc:30
30    func_a (f, "this is a string");
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000000401172 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401173 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401176 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000000000040117a <+8>: movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401181 <+15>:    movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401188 <+22>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040118c <+26>:    mov    $0x402010,%esi
   0x0000000000401191 <+31>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000401194 <+34>:    call   0x401140 <_Z6func_a5foo_tPKc>
=> 0x0000000000401199 <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040119e <+44>:    leave
   0x000000000040119f <+45>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Notice the `=>` marker, which indicates where GDB thinks we will next execute in that particular frame, i.e. the return address within that frame.

And finally, for local variables, we can use `info locals`:

```
(gdb) frame
#3  0x0000000000401199 in main () at test.cc:30
30    func_a (f, "this is a string");
(gdb) info locals 
f = {
  a = 1,
  b = 2
}
(gdb) down
#2  0x000000000040116f in func_a (arg=..., str=0x402010 "this is a string") at test.cc:23
23    func_b (arg, var + 6, str);
(gdb) info locals 
var = 123
```

The output here is very like `info args`, but GDB is just printing the stack locals.

You can always print particular locals, arguments, or globals like `print var` -- assuming of course, that you are in a frame where that variable is valid.

To learn more, GDB has a built-in help system, so you can do `help COMMAND` to get more info, e.g. `help info locals`.  There is also a basic search feature, `apropos KEYWORD`, though this is pretty crude, if the command name, or help text doesn't contain KEYWORD, you'll not find a match.  But it can sometimes be useful.

Finally, the GDB documentation is pretty extensive, and is online [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/).

Answer (score 0):

lldb works pretty much the same way with some little differences.  There isn't an summary `info frame` command like the one shown, but you can gather that from other sources.  For instance, the return address is the value of `reg read pc` in the parent frame...

To get the frame pointer, stack pointer and pc for a frame, do:

```
(lldb) f <N>
```

to select the frame, then:

```
(lldb) reg read fp sp pc
```

The return PC of frame N is the pc of frame N+1, so you can use `up` and then `reg read pc` to see that.

Some slight differences, in lldb:

(lldb) f

takes you to the 0th frame, and

(lldb) frame info

shows you where you are.

If you want to see any of these values in the `bt` output, you can add them to your frame format (use `${frame.pc}`, `${frame.fp}` etc. as described here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/formatting.html

The default frame formatting will print function arguments, but like with gdb structures are printed in a summary form so as not to unduly bloat the `bt` output.

To see the variables/full values of the arguments for a frame, do:

```
(lldb) frame var
```

(`v` is the short alias for this).  If you want to omit either args or locals use `--no-args` or `--no-locals`, and if you want to tell them apart pass `--scope` to see the variable scopes.

And as with gdb, lldb has a `help` command for getting help on commands and an `apropos` command to do word search in the help.

One little tricky bit specifically w.r.t. frame printing is that if you look closely at the source listing in a frame other than the 0th frame, the pc won't be quite right.  That's a little fiction lldb uses because the actual value of the pc when you return to the function will be AFTER the function call, and it looks really weird to have a frame say:

```
     foo();
=>   printf("but the stack says I'm executing foo");
```

IIRC gdb plays the same game.  But if you switch to the frame and run `reg read pc` you will get the real return value.

Comment: I think gdb's output is a lot more detailed than lldb's, and I don't quite understand exactly what the addresses in lldb's output represent (which may have something to do with the fact that I don't know much about the arm architecture)... Anyway, thanks a lot!